# Patent Abandoned

Tags: abandoned

I inherited this patent unfortunately I'm just becoming aware of the paperwork and or knowledge to this as of June 2020. I apologize for any inconveniences.
Thank you for your time

Comment: Unless you specify the patent number we can’t help you. Also it isn’t clear what you are asking.

Comment: If you end up petitioning for revival you may be asked to assert that every minute of delay in paying any files and filing any response was unavoidable.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the actual patent number, it is impossible to provide specific guidance. For US patents, there are periodic maintenance fees required to maintain the patent. If those fees aren't paid, the patent may expire early. It is possible, in some cases, to reinstate an expired patent. [This USPTO page](https://www.uspto.gov/patents/maintain) describes what is required to maintain a patent.